# Change date Format or String length of lable ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, date

Is there a way to format the text I get from my dataset (which is a date type) to not show time.

I had it in my sql query to format the date to not show time, but then I had to change it into a string and I need the datatype to still be a Date.

So I cant user This any more...

> CONVERT(varchar(15),em.endDate,111) as endDate  -->  2001/05/05

And this doesn't work

> CONVERT(Date,em.endDate,111)   --> Output : Output : 5/5/2001 12:00:00 AM

Here is my Template.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="endDate" SortExpression="endDate">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("endDate") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Is there a way to maybe modify the template to cut out the Time of the date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ToShortDateString`:

```
Text='<%# ((DateTime)Eval("endDate")).ToShortDateString() %>'
```

or

```
Text='<%#Eval("endDate","{0:d}")%>'
```

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Or use `RowDataBound` (assuming `GridView`, works also in other webdatabound controls like Repeater with `ItemDataBound` event):

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row; // you might use a different datasource, use the debugger if you are unsure
        Label lblEndDate = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblEndDate");
        lblEndDate.Text = row.Field<DateTime>("endDate").ToString("d");
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful if Eval("endDate") is DBNull.

Comment: In my case, because "created" can be null so I put a check before casting to DateTime like this <%# Eval("created") == DBNull.Value ? "" : ((DateTime)Eval("created")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="MyDate"  HeaderText="MyDate">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMyDate" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("MyDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EndDate","{0: dd- MMM - yyyy}")%>' />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

You can parse the string as a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx), and use the `ToString` method to format it without the time.

Depending on the format you want, you would do something like

```
myDateTime.ToString("d MMM yyy");
```